# How can I let radio's selection checked from AJAX's response?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

How can I let radio's selection button checked from  AJAX's response?
thanks!
I can get all values from AJAX's response(like {"aID":3,"aType":"type3",aText:"abctext"}) ,
but radio's button is not checked(type3 is not checked).

Here is part of my code.

```
//controller.java
@GetMapping(value = "/abcEdit/{aID}", produces = { "application/json" })
    public String editAbcView(@PathVariable Integer aID, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("aID", aID);
        return "abcEditGo";
    }
```

```
//abcEditGo.jsp
window.onload = function() {
    var aID = document.getElementById("aID");
    var aType = document.querySelectorAll("#aType")
    var aText= document.getElementById("aText");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "<c:url value='/abcEdit/" + aID + "' />", true);
    xhr.send(); 
    var message = "";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           var abcBean = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
           aID.innerHTML = abcBean.aID;
           aType.value = abcBean.aType;    
           aText.value = abcBean.aText;
-
-
-
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align='center'>
<div id='resultMsg' style="height:18px; font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <fieldset style='display: inline-block; width: 820px;'> 
    <table border='1'>
    <tr height='60'>
        <td width='400'>
            ID: <label id="aID" ></label><br>
        </td>

    </tr>   
    <tr height='60'>
        <td width='400'>
            Type:
            <input type="radio" name="aType" id="aType" value="type1">type1
            <input type="radio" name="aType" id="aType" value="type2">type1
            <input type="radio" name="aType" id="aType" value="type3">type3
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr height='60'>
        <td width='400'>
            text <input type="text" name="aText" id='aText'><br>
        </td>   
    </tr>

-
-
-
```

Comment: Try : `document.querySelector("[name=aType][value="+abcBean.aType+"]").checked = true`

Comment: @Swati Thank you .  I  try it , but it still not work.

Comment: Are you seeing any error ? Is `abcBean.aType` showing correct value ?

Comment: Chrome and Eclipse doesn't show error . I think abcBean.aType got value , but radio's buttom  doesn't  checked.

Comment: It `q_Type` and `p_Class` there . Did you change that in your original code as well and tried ?

Comment: I try again , 
Chrome's Consle show :  Uncaught ReferenceError: QuesBean is not defined at window.onload .